# Brave Tracing in Kafka Headers

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth, brave

In SB2, Brave instruments Kafka messages with B3 headers by default, however I need to change the field names that are injected. E.g. X-B3-TraceId should be myEventTraceId. Is there an easy way to do this? Even some design guidance would help greatly. Wouldnt mind a simple example... KafkaTracing and Injector classes come to mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up wrapping the producer returned in `createProducer()` of my custom `ProducerFactory` in a custom delegate class that implements `Producer`. My implementation of `send()` executed after Brave's `TracingProducer.send()` such that I could modify the tracing headers Brave set in the `ProducerRecord` headers prior to sending the bits. The same logic applies when consuming.

Comment: I have similar challenge. Could you please share some code showing how you implemented that?

Comment: Im sorry, I can't, however I've given a straight forward explanation. Post what you have.

Comment: What do you mean by delegate class? I am using kafkaTemplate.send. How can I achieve what you did? Did u not use spring cloud sleuth at all?

Comment: Im not at a PC, so I cant code right now. A delegate pattern is a simple wrapper class. Yes, I used brave.

Comment: I am not understanding. How could you inject your own X-B3-TraceId header right before producer.send() is called? Because Brave injects headers just before that happens.

Comment: Correct, Brave does inject them. Does the ConsumerRecord API, not allow for  modifying headers?